# Should I manualy disable React StrictMode in production?

Tags: reactjs, react-strictmode

I was reading the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) and learned that React `StrictMode` is for *development only*, and it explains why we have double invoke.

That's great, but does it mean I have to disable the `StrictMode` manualy for my production, or does react `build` command does it on its own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stright from the [Beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/StrictMode):

##### Strict Mode enables the following checks in development:

- Your components will re-render an extra time to find bugs caused by impure rendering.
- Your components will re-run Effects an extra time to find bugs caused by missing Effect cleanup.
- Your components will be checked for usage of deprecated APIs.

##### All of these checks are development-only and do not impact the production build.

Comment: I already love this beta doc ! Thank you